# hide/show a table onclick not working inside div

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have a table inside a div element

```
<div id="E" ng-model="total">
    <div ng-if="total.passfail" onclick="showE1()">{{total.passfail}} scripts Passed in {{Listbox}} and failed in {{Comparebox}}</div>
    <table width="100%" id="E1">                            
        <thead>
            ...lots of trs and tds                                  
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            ...lots of trs and tds
        </tbody>
    </table>  
 </div>
```

On clicking the text it should call showE1 and hide/display the table.  When i debug it , it enters the function showE1 onclick but display is not changing. Is there a rookie mistake that i'm making ?

```
function showE1(){  
      document.getElementById("E1").style.display = "block" ? "none" : "block";
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery as well or just java script?

Comment: No jquery. Angular js and javascript.

Comment: Hi Rahul, being you are using AngularJS I'd suggest you'd look into [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)/[ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) instead of doing it the way you're doing it

Comment: ok Lee i'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator will return "none" if "block" is truthy, and "block" if it isn't. Since "block" is a constant and evaluates to truthy

```
document.getElementById("E1").style.display = "block" ? "none" : "block";
```

Will always return "none".
Were you going for this?

```
document.getElementById("E1").style.display = (document.getElementById("E1").style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an inline-if statement, but your logic test is simply "block". If you ask Javascript "block?", this does not result in a true/false. You need to be testing if the current value equals "block".

Comment: do you mean if(document.getElementById("E1").style.display=='block'), cuz that did not work too.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working the way you did.

```js
               function showE1()
                {   

                    document.getElementById("E1").style.display = "block" ? "none" : "block";
                }
```

```html
             <div id="E" ng-model="total">
                <div ng-if="total.passfail" onclick="showE1()">{{total.passfail}} scripts Passed in {{Listbox}} and failed in {{Comparebox}}</div>


                    <table width="100%" id="E1">


                        <thead>
                            <tr><td>Something</td></tr>

                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>Something else</td></tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>  
 </div>
```

Double check if the code running on your test platform is actually the one you post as question.

Comment: Nope, checked it again.   document.getElementById("E1").style.display = (document.getElementById("E1").style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";  is working though .